# Understanding Instantiation in Swift - Why not require in custom class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

It was my understanding that in Swift you don't need to import your classes (only for some frameworks) but intatiation was required, but to my surprise this may not be true, I created a custom class (`CustomCell.swift`) for a custom cell I'm using in my UITableView and apparently there is no need to make an instance of the custom class before using it. Here is how I'm using it.

CustomCell Class

```
//  CustomCell.swift

import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelDisplayWattage: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

View Controller

```
//  ViewController.swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

// some code ...

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.labelDisplayWattage.text = String(totalWattageList[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

}
```

As you can see there are no instances of the `CustomCell` class exept for the call on method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (`as! CustomCell`).

Can someone tell me why there was no need to create an instance of class `CustomCell` before using it in method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? I was expecting to see something like...

```
var myCustomCell = CustomCell()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a really important concept underneath the code you're seeing right now. If you're using storyboards, table views and collection views have the option of using a prototype cell. A prototype cell is a template of the cell that can/will be used with the table view or collection view. If your table/collection view is set to use a prototype cell, there is no need to create a new cell,`UIKit` takes care of creating one for you when you ask for a queued cell by calling `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

Consider the following when ***NOT*** using prototype cells:

```
//  ViewController.swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

// some code ...

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomCell
        if nil == cell {
            cell = CustomCell()
            // more cell options can be set here
        }
        cell.labelDisplayWattage.text = String(totalWattageList[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using a  prototype cell. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

As per apple docs for Datasource method

```
 func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String,forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

> For performance reasons, a table view’s data source should generally
>   reuse UITableViewCell objects when it assigns cells to rows in its
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. A table view maintains a
>   queue or list of UITableViewCell objects that the data source has
>   marked for reuse. Call this method from your data source object when
>   asked to provide a new cell for the table view. **This method dequeues
>   an existing cell if one is available, or creates a new one based on
>   the class or nib file you previously registered, and adds it to the
>   table.**

so basically it creates a new object for you if the queue is empty.

**Source:** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:

Answer (score 1):

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```

Instantiation of the CustomCell is responsibility of tableview, we just fetch the cell, if the cell is not instantiated when we fetch it tableview will instantiate it before returning it to us.

This behavior is of architectural design, it is not specific to swift. It works in same way for objective-c as well.